# svg color inside fabricjs canvas not changing

Tags: javascript, three.js, fabricjs

i'm trying to change svg path's fill which is inside fabricjs canvas.

[image]

using this function

```
function changeColor(material) {

    console.log(svgGroup[0].fill)
    console.log(material);
    if (material == 'base') {
        svgGroup[0].fill = '#000000';
        console.log(svgGroup[0].fill)
    }
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    object.children[0].material = textureMaterial;
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

but it doesn't updated automatically

[image]

anyone have any idea why? any thought would be helpful

Comment: What svgGroup[0] contains? would you mind to share svg?

Comment: actually i just found the problem, the problem iwas i didn't set the color correctly. i should've use `.set('fill', color)` that way it is rendered when `renderAll()` is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, the problem iwas i didn't set the color correctly. instead of doing this

```
svgGroup[0].fill = '#000000';
```

it should've use this

```
svgGroup._objects.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.id == material) {
        obj.set('fill', color);
    }
});
```

that way it is rendered when renderAll() is called